# Angular compile error on missing dependencies

Tags: angular, angular-material

I added button but after compiling I faced this issue, let me know how to add this dependencies:

> ERROR in The target entry-point "@angular/material/button" has missing dependencies:
>   - @angular/core
>   - @angular/cdk/a11y
>   - @angular/platform-browser/animations
>   - @angular/cdk/coercion

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you use `@angular/cli` to create your project?

Comment: yes, I used @angular/cli to create my project

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "MatButtonModule" to your app.module.ts or maybe your material.module.ts. Depends on the way you have setted it up.

Be sure it is part of your imports and exports:

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  imports: [MatButtonModule],
  exports: [MatButtonModule]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
If you just installed @angular/material it possibly won't work.